# Android only one Firebase Messaging Service is working at a time

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using two firebase cloud messaging service providers to deliver and receive push notifications in my app. It is a requirement from the client and hence I cannot go against it.

The problem is that the first fcm provider service (Nifty SDK) was working pretty well until I added the second one. I have not removed any code related to the first one. Also, I am using only one FirebaseMessagingService class (as I should) to handle all the incoming notifications from both the SDKs.

Below is a relevant chunk of corresponding manifest file data for both of them:

```
       <receiver android:name=".service.ConnectionReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <receiver android:name=".service.RemovedReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
            <data android:scheme="jp.croomplus.crewmart" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".service.CustomNiftyMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <!-- 通知エリアに表示されるアイコンの設定 -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="smallIcon"
        android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <!-- 通知エリアに表示されるアイコンカラーの設定 -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="smallIconColor"
        android:value="@color/colorAccent" />

    <!-- 通知エリアにプッシュ通知を複数表示する設定　0:最新のみ表示 , 1:複数表示 -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="notificationOverlap"
        android:value="1" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/push_channel_id" />


    <!-- PPSDK related -->
    <!-- ジオエリア検知情報をユーザーへコールバックするレシーバークラス -->
    <receiver
        android:name="jp.co.evergreen.listener.PPSDKGeoAreaListener"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- ジオエリア検知イベントアクション名 -->
            <action android:name="jp.profilepassport.android.GEOAREA" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- 各種バッチ用レシーバークラス -->
    <receiver
        android:name="jp.profilepassport.android.tasks.PPScheduleReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- アプリ更新イベント -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- 時間変更イベント -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
            <!-- Locale変更イベント -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED" />
            <!-- 起動イベント -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <!-- Bluetooth状態変更イベント -->
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED" />
            <!-- 位置情報使用状態変更イベント -->
            <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- Push通知開封イベント用Service -->
    <service android:name="jp.profilepassport.android.notification.PPNotificationService" />

    <!-- ジオエリア検知用BroadcastReceiver -->
    <receiver android:name="jp.profilepassport.android.geoarea.receiver.PPGeoAreaReceiver" />

    <!-- WiFi検知用Service -->
    <service android:name="jp.profilepassport.android.wifi.service.PPWifiScanService" />

    <!-- PPSDKのJobScheduler実行Service -->
    <service
        android:name="jp.profilepassport.android.schedule.PPJobService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>

    <!-- ログ作成用JobScheduler実行Service -->
    <service
        android:name="jp.profilepassport.android.logger.PPLoggerJobService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>

    <!-- ログ作成用レシーバークラス -->
    <receiver
        android:name="jp.profilepassport.android.logger.PPLoggerReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- アプリ更新イベント -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- 起動イベント -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="jp.profilepassport.android.logger.action.PP_LOGGER_ACTION" />
            <!-- 時間変更イベント -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
            <!-- タイムゾーン変更イベント -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- ProfilePassportSdkのマニフェスト ここまで -->
```

Upto "PPSDK related" tag is the relevant data for one of the SDKs (Nifty SDK). From "PPSDK related tag" to the end is the relevant data for the other SDK (PPSDK). Both of these SDKs are using FCM service.

I have customized the FirebaseMessagingService class according to both the docs:

```
public class CustomNiftyMessagingService extends NCMBFirebaseMessagingService {
public static final String FROM_PUSH = "FROM_PUSH";
private final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private final String TITLE = "title";
private final String MESSAGE = "message";
private final String PAYLOAD = "com.nifty.Data";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // PPSDKにRemoteMessageを渡して、処理呼び出し
    PPSDKManager.onMessageReceived(getApplicationContext(), remoteMessage);

    String title = remoteMessage.getData().get(TITLE);
    String message = remoteMessage.getData().get(MESSAGE);
    String payload = remoteMessage.getData().get(PAYLOAD);

    // json文字列を変換
    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        CategoryInfo categoryInfo = gson.fromJson(payload, CategoryInfo.class);
        NiftyPreference preference = new NiftyPreference(getApplicationContext());
        preference.setCategoryInfo(categoryInfo);
    } catch (Exception error) {
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
    PendingIntent intent = createPendingIntent();

    NotificationDirector director;
    INotificationBuilder builder;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        builder = new NotificationBuilderForOreo(this, getString(R.string.push_channel_id));
    } else {
        builder = new NotificationBuilder(this, getString(R.string.push_channel_id));
    }

    director = new NotificationDirector(builder);
    director.constract(title, message, intent);

    NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.getResult());
}

@Override
public void onMessageSent(String s) {
    super.onMessageSent(s);
    // PPSDK処理呼び出し
    PPSDKManager.onMessageSent(s);
}

@Override
public void onDeletedMessages() {
    super.onDeletedMessages();
    // PPSDK処理呼び出し
    PPSDKManager.onDeletedMessages();
}

@Override
public void onSendError(String s, Exception e) {
    super.onSendError(s, e);
    // PPSDK処理呼び出し
    PPSDKManager.onSendError(s, e);
}

@Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
    Log.d("PPSDK Sample", "############# onNewToken : " + s);
    // PPSDK処理呼び出し
    PPSDKManager.onTokenRefresh(getApplicationContext());
}

private PendingIntent createPendingIntent() {
    // 表示したいActivityを指定する
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtra(FROM_PUSH, true);
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
}
```

}

Here, NCMBFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService. In PPSDK docs, it is said that if we only write the following line inside @onMessageReceived(), it will handle the PPSDK related notifications automatically (and it indeed was doing so):

```
PPSDKManager.onMessageReceived(getApplicationContext(), remoteMessage);
```

But right after I have implemented it, PPSDK is working perfectly but the previously functioning Nifty messaging service has stopped delivering push notifications.

I have tried stopping the call to start the PPSDK service, but Nifty is still not working after disabling the start call to PPSDK service. I have made sure that my APP_KEY, CLIENT_TOKEN, etc for both the SDKs are absolutely okay. Also uninstalled and freshly installed multiple times. But the issue is not solved yet.

What seems to be the problem here? Is it because of the common 'notification_channel_id'? Or did anything get altered irrevocably at the server side after PPSDK started to work?